# Store values in realm

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

I am creating a fitness journal app, and I store workout values in realm this this:
[image: iest]

I am sorting the workouts using date. I want to accomplish something new, where I can have different weight and reps each set on the same exercise. It is based on this design:
[image]

I think the database has to bee something like this, but not sure:

> - 23.11.2019
>
>   - Barbell Bench Press
>
>     - Set 1
>
>       - KG: 90
>       - Reps: 5
>     - Set 2
>
>       - KG: 87,5
>       - Reps: 6
>   - Triceps Pushdown
>
>     - Set 1
>
>       - KG: 110
>       - Reps: 6
>     - Set 2
>
>       - KG: 110
>       - Reps: 6
>     - Set 3
>
>       - KG: 112,5
>       - Reps: 5

Any tips on how I can do this?

Edit;
This is my current `Workout.swift` class (not sure how to edit it to get what I want):

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    @objc dynamic var exercise: String?
    @objc dynamic var sets = 0
    @objc dynamic var reps = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?

}
```

Comment: @Sammy Updated question with class now :)

Comment: The question is a little vague. I see your comment to the (incorrect) answer but it's still unclear. Are you stating that your sets var should actually be a [List](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/List.html) (hint hint) of steps? So the sets List would contain objects that have three properties; an index, num_reps and weight? Where the index would be the step #; index 0 = step 0, index 1 = step 1 and each step has the associated number of reps and weight for that step

Comment: @Jay The problem is I om not sure how I should set this up. Tried to create it how I want it like this; https://ibb.co/rw9x8BK - Hope that helps.

Comment: @rs7 has an excellent answer and provides a clear example based on my comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to have three objects (Workout, Exercise, and Set) and have 2 many-to-many relationship as outlined in the documentation: https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#many-to-many

```
class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date?
    // List of exercises (to-many relationship)
    var exercises = List<Exercise>()

}
```

.

```
class Exercise: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    // List of sets (to-many relationship)
    var sets = List<Set>()
    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workout.self, property: "exercises")
}
```

.

```
class Set: Object {

    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?
    // Define an inverse relationship to be able to access your parent workout for a particular set (if needed)
    var parentExercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: Exercise.self, property: "sets")

    convenience init(numReps: Int, weight: Double, aNote: String) {
       self.init()
       self.reps = numReps
       self.kg = weight
       self.notes = aNote
    }

}
```

EDIT

adding example code

```
let aSet0 = Set(numReps: 10, weight: 5.0, aNote: "light workout")
let aSet1 = Set(numReps: 10, weight: 20.0, aNote: "medium workout")
let aSet2 = Set(numReps: 10, weight: 30.0, aNote: "heavy workout")

let aWorkout = Workout()
aWorkout.name = example
aWorkout.sets.append(objectsIn: [aSet0, aSet1, aSet2] )
```

Another example code to display the sets for the "Bench Press" workout:

```
// Find the Workout instance "Bench Press"
let benchPressWorkout = realm.objects(Workout.self).filter("name = 'Bench Press'")
// Access the sets for that instance
let sets = benchPressWorkout.sets
// Access set[0]
let set0 = sets[0]
// Access reps and kg for set 0
let reps0 = set0.reps
let kg0 = set0.kg
// and so on ...
```

Comment: Based on my comment to the question, this is a great solution. The inverse relationship is a good addition as you may want to know at some points which workouts use sets > 50Kg for example. You could also label these sets as 'Starter Set' or 'Heavy Workout Set' which makes them re-usable.

Comment: @Jay - I am new to this, but i'm I on to something right here? Trying to save a exercise: https://ibb.co/6gfqqnK

Comment: @rs7 excellent answer. I added a code example to illustrate the use. Feel free to edit.

Comment: @Camile Not sure if that's correct. I updated this answer some some example code so you get a feel for how to implement it.

Comment: @Jay Ok, nice! I managed to get saving to work now. So the classes look like this now in Realm Studio: https://ibb.co/NNRsgr2 . But there is no connection from the exercise to the number of reps/kg, so I cant display what exercise has what data? So how can I/the user know what exercise has 10 number of reps, with 5kg and aNote; light workout?

Comment: @Camile Not sure what that means exactly as there's a direct relationship between the workout and the sets that go with it. If you are asking about getting additional data from the objects in sets, it's essentially an array you can iterate over or if appropriate you can utilize the [aggregate expressions](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering) to get a sum of the kg for example. If it's something more then this question has been answered (be sure to accept this answer) and maybe post another question.

Comment: @Jay As you can see in the picture on my answer, you will see previous weight with number of reps, and the new amount og weight and reps. They are connected to the exercise: "Bench Press (Dumbbell). How can I do this in my case?

Comment: @Camile There is a connection between the exercise type and the number of reps/weight. That connection is made by accessing the variable "sets." For example, if you want to display the sets for the "Bench press (Dumbell)" workout, you would just query the Workout class with name == "Bench press (Dumbell)", and display the list "sets". Does this make sense?

Comment: @Camile I added another example that will help you understand how to display the "Bench Press" table in your post.

Comment: @rs7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59013865/get-data-from-realm-list

Comment: I updated my answer. Previous answer was incorrect. You need three classes: Workout, Exercise, Set. A workout is composed of one or more exercises, and an exercise is composed of one or more sets.

Comment: @rs7 When using three objects - how can I display them in the cellForRow? When the workout contains multiple objects(exercises), I want to display the exercise name for each of the exercise in cells.

Answer (score 0):

Create a WorkOut this way

```
let realm = try! Realm()
var wo = WorkOut()//Do initialization for properties such as name,reps,...
try! realm.write{
   realm.add(wo)
}
```

One record of WorkOut is written to your database

Comment: Thanks, but I think you misunderstood my question. I already know how to save to realm, because I am already using the database I provided in my first image. Currently, it saves the workout like this: Bench Press , 3 sets, 5 reps, 80kg. But I want to change it to something like: Bench Press ; first set, 5 reps 75kg, second set, 4 reps 77,5kg, third set, 3 reps 80kg.

Comment: I want to create a realm database that looks something like this: https://ibb.co/rw9x8BK

Comment: Where does it crash and what error are you getting? Technically, you need to open a new thread for a new issue like this.