# Get data from Realm List<>

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, realm

So this is how my Realm classes looks like:

```
class Workout: Object {

    @objc dynamic var date: Date? // Date I did the exercise
    @objc dynamic var exercise: String? // Name of exercise, example; Bench Press, Squat, Deadlift etc..
    // List of sets (to-many relationship)
    var sets = List<Set>()

}
```

---

```
class Set: Object {

    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0 // Number of reps for the each set
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0 // Amount of weight/kg for each set
    @objc dynamic var notes: String? // Notes for each set

    // Define an inverse relationship to be able to access your parent workout for a particular set (if needed)
    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workout.self, property: "sets")

    convenience init(numReps: Int, weight: Double, aNote: String) {
       self.init()
       self.reps = numReps
       self.kg = weight
       self.notes = aNote
    }
}
```

I want to get the weight(kg) and number of reps for each set, from the last time I did this exercise. So I am trying something like this. To query a workout with `exercise` "Text Exercise2", I do this:

```
func queryFromRealm() {
    let realm = try! Realm()

    let getExercises = realm.objects(Workout.self).filter("exercise = 'Text Exercise2'").sorted(byKeyPath: "date",ascending: false)

    print(getExercises.last!)

    myTableView.reloadData()
}
```

That gives me an output of this:

```
Workout {
    date = 2019-11-24 00:33:21 +0000;
    exercise = Text Exercise2;
    sets = List<Set> <0x600003fcdb90> (
        [0] Set {
            reps = 12;
            kg = 7;
            notes = light workout;
        },
        [1] Set {
            reps = 12;
            kg = 8;
            notes = medium workout;
        },
        [2] Set {
            reps = 12;
            kg = 9;
            notes = heavy workout;
        }
    );
}
```

This is how I am passing data from mainVC to ExerciseCreatorViewController:

```
var selectedWorkout = Workout()
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "toEditExerciseCreatorSegue" {
            if let nextVC = segue.destination as? ExerciseCreatorViewController {
                nextVC.selectedWorkout = self.selectedWorkout
            }
        }
    }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)

        selectedWorkout = resultFromDate[indexPath.row]

        performSegue(withIdentifier: "toEditExerciseCreatorSegue", sender: self)
    }
```

From now on, I want to add these into at `UITableView`, where each row contains the kg and number of reps. How can I do this? Should I change my setup somehow? Looking forward for your help.

EDIT - Uploaded the whole ExerciseCreatorViewController.swift file:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ExerciseCreatorViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    let menuButtonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44, height: 44)
    let actionButtonSize: CGSize = CGSize(width: 44, height: 66)
    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var resultFromDate:[Workout] = []
    var selectedWorkout = Workout()


    @IBOutlet var exerciseNameTextField: UITextField!
    let exerciseName = UILabel()

    @IBOutlet var navView: UIView!
    let navLabel = UILabel()

    @IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        exerciseNameTextField.delegate = self

        // Get main screen bounds
        let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
        let screenWidth = screenSize.width
        let screenHeight = screenSize.height

        //self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255, alpha: 1.0)
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        // Navigation View
        navView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 66)
        navView.frame.origin.y = 28
        //navLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 32/255, green: 32/255, blue: 32/255, alpha: 1.0)
        navLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        //navView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        self.view.addSubview(navView)

        // Navigation Label
        self.navView.addSubview(navLabel)
        navLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 66)
        navLabel.textAlignment = .center
        navLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        navLabel.textColor = UIColor.black
        //navLabel.text = "Workout"
        navLabel.text = "Log workout"
        navLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        navLabel.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white

        configureButtons()

        setupFooter()

        self.hideKeyboard()

        print("Printing ... ... ...")
        print(selectedWorkout)
    }

    func setupFooter() {
        let customView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 50))
        customView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
        let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenSize.width, height: 50))
        button.setTitle("Add Set", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        customView.addSubview(button)

        tableView.tableFooterView = customView
    }

    @objc func buttonAction(_ sender: UIButton!) { // Add new set/row in tableView
        print("Button tapped")

        let a = Array(stride(from: 1, through: 50, by: 1)) // Haven't tested yet. Add new set in array

        setsArray.append("a")

        // Update Table Data
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        tableView.insertRows(at: [
            (NSIndexPath(row: setsArray.count-1, section: 0) as IndexPath)
        ], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }

     func configureButtons() {
           confiureCloseButton()
           confiureSaveButton()
           confiureClearButton()
       }

       func confiureCloseButton() {
           //let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 100, y: 100, width: 100, height: 50))
           let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint.zero, size: menuButtonSize))
           button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_close"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
           button.setImage(UIImage(named: "icon_close")?.alpha(0.5), for: UIControl.State.highlighted)
           button.center = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 61)
           button.layer.cornerRadius = button.frame.size.width/2
           button.layer.zPosition = 1
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
           button.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControl.State.normal)
           button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           self.view.addSubview(button)
       }

       @objc func closeButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
           self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
       }



       func confiureSaveButton() {
           let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: screenSize.width-44-8, y: 28), size: actionButtonSize))
           button.setTitle("Save", for: UIControl.State.normal)
           //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
           button.layer.zPosition = 1
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(saveButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
           button.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControl.State.normal)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           self.view.addSubview(button)
       }

       @objc func saveButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
           saveWorkout()
       }

       func confiureClearButton() {
           let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: screenSize.width-44-8-44-8, y: 28), size: actionButtonSize))
           button.setTitle("Clear", for: UIControl.State.normal)
           //button.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
           button.layer.zPosition = 1
           button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(clearButtonAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
           button.setTitleColor(.black, for: UIControl.State.normal)

           self.view.addSubview(button)
       }

       @objc func clearButtonAction(sender: UIButton!) {
           clearWorkout()
       }

    func clearWorkout() { // Clear workout exercise
        print("clear")
    }
    let nowDate = Date()




    var setsArray = [String]()
    var previousArray = [String]()
    var kgArray = [String]()
    var repsArray = [String]()
    var notesArray = [String]()

    func saveWorkout() { // Save workout exercise
        if setsArray.isEmpty {//if !setsArray.isEmpty {
            print("Saving workout...")
            /*let realm = try! Realm()


            let myWorkout = Workout()
            myWorkout.date = nowDate
            myWorkout.exercise = "Text Exercise"

            let aSet0 = Set(numReps: 12, weight: 11.5, aNote: "light workout")
            let aSet1 = Set(numReps: 12, weight: 12.5, aNote: "medium workout")
            let aSet2 = Set(numReps: 12, weight: 21.0, aNote: "heavy workout")

            myWorkout.sets.append(objectsIn: [aSet0, aSet1, aSet2] )

            try! realm.write {
                realm.add(myWorkout)
                print("Saved!")
            }*/
        } else {

            // create the alert
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "Please add any exercise before saving!", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)

            // add an action (button)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: nil))

            // show the alert
            self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }

    // number of rows in table view
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return setsArray.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExerciseCreatorCell

        let realm = try! Realm()
        let getExercises = realm.objects(Workout.self).filter("exercise = 'Text Exercise2'").sorted(byKeyPath: "date",ascending: false)

        print(getExercises.last!)

        let myWorkout = Workout()

        // Find the Workout instance "Bench Press"
        let benchPressWorkout = realm.objects(Workout.self).filter("exercise = 'Text Exercise2'").sorted(byKeyPath: "date",ascending: false)
        // Access the sets for that instance
        let sets = benchPressWorkout[0].sets

        for i in sets.indices {
            let set0 = sets[i]

            // Access reps and kg for set 0
            let reps0 = set0.reps
            let kg0 = set0.kg
            // and so on ...

            print([kg0]) // number of KG
            print([reps0]) // number of reps

            cell.previousTextField.text = "\(kg0) x \(reps0)"

        }

        cell.setLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row + 1)"

        return cell
    }

    // method to run when table view cell is tapped
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        print("tapped")
    }
}
```

EDIT: I have three objects as @rs7 suggested earlier:

Workout.swift:

```
@objc dynamic var id = 0
@objc dynamic var date: Date?
// List of exercises (to-many relationship)
var exercises = List<Exercise>()

override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
    return "id"
}
```

Exercise.swift

```
class Exercise: Object {

    @objc dynamic var name: String?
    // List of sets (to-many relationship)
    var sets = List<Set>()
    var parentWorkout = LinkingObjects(fromType: Workout.self, property: "exercises")
}
```

Set.swift

```
class Set: Object {

    @objc dynamic var reps: Int = 0
    @objc dynamic var kg: Double = 0.0
    @objc dynamic var notes: String?
    // Define an inverse relationship to be able to access your parent workout for a particular set (if needed)
    var parentExercise = LinkingObjects(fromType: Exercise.self, property: "sets")

    convenience init(numReps: Int, weight: Double, aNote: String) {
       self.init()
       self.reps = numReps
       self.kg = weight
       self.notes = aNote
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what the question is here. You know how to get the data from Realm and the output it to the console. So... are you asking how to work with tableViews? If you don't need the data live updating, then use the standard practice used with tableViews; create a class to hold the data you want to display, build the class from the *sets* List (by iterating over sets), and then store those classes in your tableView dataSource array. Can you clarify?

Comment: I agree with Jay, can you give more specifics? Are you trying to display your last workout? In other words, you'd have last Work comprised of one of more exercises and each exercise will be comprised of one or more sets -- am I understanding this correctly (btw, make sure you check my update answer in your previous post. You need to have 3 classes, not 2)

Comment: @rs7 - Yes, I am trying to display my previous data for that specific exercise in tablview. So let's say I have registered the exercise `Text Exercise2 `for xx amount of times, and I want to retrieve the kg and reps for all the sets from the last time I did that exercise, to create something like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tUIL.png (ref my other question here in SO).

Comment: Let's call the exercise you are trying to display selectedExercise (of type Exercise). You'd basically set the number of rows for your tableview to selectedExercise.sets.count + 2. In other words, that's your number of sets + one row for the header + one row for "Add Set". Then in your cellForRowAt function, you would configure the first and last row of your table to respectively be your header and your "Add Set" cell. (you can use guard statements for that) As for displaying the sets information, you would use selectedExercise.sets[indexPath.row - 1]

Comment: And you would access reps and kg by appending .kg and .reps to selectedExercise.sets[indexPath.row - 1]. If you need a more detailed answer, you need to provide me with some code and some context and I'll be happy to help. Also, just like Jay suggested, please accept the answer in the other thread if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: @rs7 What kind of code would you like in order to show as an example? Is there any place we can chat? Yes, I accepted the answer in the other thread now, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks! The code for the ViewController that displays the table. Also, how are you passing the value for the current exercise being displayed? It's probably coming from the previous ViewController that would display a list of exercises?

Comment: @rs7 Added the whole `ExerciseCreatorViewController.swift` file now. This is the ViewController that should register the exercise like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tUIL.png

Comment: @rs7 Did you have time to take a look? :)

Comment: Must have missed your previous message. Will take a look.

Comment: Before I start helping you, you need to find a way to pass the Exercise object you are trying to display. For example, if the previous ViewController is displaying a list of Exercises and the user taps on one and it triggers a segue to ExerciseCreatorViewController, you need to pass the value of that Exercise object using prepareForSegue. You would obviously need to create a displayedExercise (or selectedExercise) variable inside your ExerciseCreatorViewController. Does that make sense?

Comment: @rs7 Yes, I know how to do that. I can store them as an array for example I guess?

Comment: You would just pass the Exercise object so a variable of type Exercise.

Comment: @rs7 Yes, of course, sorry that is what I mean.

Comment: Also, make sure you have 3 different tableViewCells: one for the header, one for the entries, and finally, one for adding a new set. Please update your code when that is done and I should be able to post my answer. Include the tableViewCells code.

Comment: @rs7 Do I need 3 cells for that? I have one cell for the entries, and I have a footer for adding a new set, ref `func setupFooter() `.

Comment: I guess you could do it with one cell in this case.

Comment: @rs7 Now I have done what you said - added passing data from VC to VC. Code updated in `ViewController.swift`. Please have a look :)

Comment: Just to be clear: are you displaying a workout or an exercise with several sets? In your code you are passing a Workout object to the next ViewController. Based on the picture you shared on the other thread, you should be passing an Exercise object. Also, did you update your data model? Look at the other thread and make sure you have 3 distinct objects (Workout, Exercise, Set)

Comment: @rs7 When perform `didSelectRowAt`, I am displaying an exercise with several sets in the next viewController. No, I haven't updated it yet, but I can do it now. By the way; I am not using `@objc dynamic var name: String?` anymore. I wanted remove it because it's not something I'm going to need/use. Do I still need 3 distinct objects, or should I stay on the 2 I currently have?

Comment: @rs7 I can see at my last edit I mixed some code from two viewController. Updated now, to display the passing of the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203207/discussion-between-rs7-and-camile).

Answer (score 0):

I'll give you the answer anyway, but don't forget to fix your code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // number of rows = number of sets (not counting the header row)
    return selectedExercise.sets.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! ExerciseCreatorCell
    let currentSet = selectedExercise.sets[indexPath.row]
    cell.setNumberLabel.text = "\(indexPath.row)"
    cell.kgLabel.text = "\(currentSet.kg)"
    cell.repsLabel.text = "\(currentSet.reps)"
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203793/discussion-on-answer-by-rs7-get-data-from-realm-list).

Comment: When using the three objects - how can I display them in the cellForRow? This answer is based on two Objects(?) When the workout contains multiple objects(exercises), I want to display the exercise name for each of the exercise in cells. (Question updated with edit also)